# Calculating SAD for 128 elements, given two uint8_t arrays

Tags: c, optimization, simd, avx, avx2

I have two arrays of `uint8_t` which both have 64 elements.
The "best" way I've come up with, to calculate SAD on all of them, is to load 4x 16 elements, put them into two `m128i` registers, and then put them both into a `m256` register. This is done for both `uint8_t` arrays, like so:

```
__m128i a1, a2, b1, b2, s1, s2;
__m256i u, v, c;

// 128 bit of data x 2
a1 = _mm_set_epi64(*(__m64*)block1, *((__m64*)(block1 + stride)));
block1 += stride + stride;
a2 = _mm_set_epi64(*(__m64*)block1, *((__m64*)(block1 + stride)));

// the upper 128 bits of the result are undefined
u = _mm256_castsi128_si256(a1);
// Copy a to dst, then insert 128 bits from b into dst at the location specified by imm.
u = _mm256_insertf128_si256(u, a2, 0x1);

b1 = _mm_set_epi64(*(__m64*)block2, *((__m64*)(block2 + stride)));
block2 += stride + stride;
b2 = _mm_set_epi64(*(__m64*)block2, *((__m64*)(block2 + stride)));

// the upper 128 bits of the result are undefined
v = _mm256_castsi128_si256(b1);
// Copy a to dst, then insert 128 bits from b into dst at the location specified by imm.
v = _mm256_insertf128_si256(v, b2, 0x1);
```

I now have two `m256` registers, `u` and `v`, and can calculate the SAD:

```
c = _mm256_sad_epu8(u, v);
```

However, probably due to late hours, I could not come up with a better way of getting the result ...
This is what I have got now:

```
s1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256(c, 0x0);
s2 = _mm256_extractf128_si256(c, 0x1);

int p, q;
p = _mm_extract_epi32(s1, 0x0);
q = _mm_extract_epi32(s1, 0x2);
*result += p + q;

p = _mm_extract_epi32(s2, 0x0);
q = _mm_extract_epi32(s2, 0x2);
*result += p + q;
```

`result` is an int, if it's unclear.

This is generating quite a bit of instructions. In my eyes, it is the only way to load all the uints i want. However, it's probably *not* the best way to get the result out of the `m256i c` register.

What do you say? **Can you help me do this in a more optimized way?**

Put together, the function looks something like:

```
void foobar(uint8_t *block1, uint8_t *block2, int stride, int *result)
{
  *result = 0;
  int i;
  __m128i a1, a2, b1, b2, s1, s2;
  __m256i u, v, c;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    // loading of uints
    // calculating SAD, and getting result

    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
    block1 += stride; block2 += stride;
  }
}
```

Due do the nature of how the uints are organized, I can only load eight at a time, before I have to increment the address with `stride`. Loading i.e. sixteen at once, would yield a bad result.

Comment: Can you explain further why you cannot load more than 8 at a time? Can you describe in words or with an ASCII diagram the memory layout of the 64 pairs of 8-bit unsigned ints and which pairs are absdiffed?

Comment: Look at the `for` loop in the last code example. Notice how I must increment the memory addresses of both `block1` and `block2` with `stride`. The elements I want follow this equation: `block1[stride * y + x]`, where `y = [0, >` and `x = [0, 7]`

Comment: What is `stride`? I'm guessing it is not 8? If it were, your code above could be replaced by just one unaligned `__m256` load. If it is 16, I'd still use a load of a `__m256`. If it isn't any of those, well then I wouldn't even bother with the shuffles, since every cycle you spend shuffling 8-byte groups is a cycle you don't spend on `MOVDQU`, `PSADBW` and `PADDQ`.

Comment: Are `block1` and `block2` interleaved?

Comment: This is part of a motion estimation algorithm, and stride is basically the width of the video. So the value of stride may be whatever.

Comment: It's a ME algorithm! Oh, then can you use `VMPSADBW`? That instruction is gold for ME.

Comment: I have looked at it, but this would require that I calculate the SAD of four 8-bit blocks right? Can you perhaps give a short example of the use? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, can I just confirm that you're SAD-ing an 8x8 block of 8-bit unsigned against multiple neighbouring 8x8 blocks? Also, a white paper by Intel on just this topic is [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/motion-estimation-with-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4)

Comment: yes, that is the idea. Apart from the `stride` parameter, that is correct. I load eight and eight bytes at a time, then increment with `stride` and load again. Same structure for both `block1` and `block2`

Comment: And what is the neighbourhood, if you will, that the 8x8 block is being compared against? Is it, say, ±4 horizontally and vertically about a center point? Because MPSADBW does a four-element 8-bit unsigned SAD at eight consecutive spatial locations; So if it's not convenient for you we should ditch this idea.

Comment: Sorry if I don't follow you, but the SAD value of `block1` and `block2`, is compared to the "previous" SAD value. After each calculation, we advance to the next `(x, y)` point. Assuming we are on the same `y` axis, the `block2` address is just incremented by `1` each time. Don't know if I answered you at all.. I'm not that in to the whole motion estimation stuff, but I can probably find out if you can clarify what you need answered? Sorry, again.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that when you advance to the next `(x, y)` point, how many increments of `x` do you do before incrementing `y`?

Comment: Heh, that depends, really.. If you look here: http://pastebin.com/XaCFG5RR you'll see that the `x` starts off at `left` and goes till `right`. These values...well, are not always the same. Depends on the video.

Comment: Almost there; I'm exactly after the value of `range`. What can be said of its value for the common case, assuming you're bumping against the border? Is it `1`? `8`? `16`?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my example usage of `VMPSADBW`?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to getting the sum of the absolute differences from two byte arrays this his how I would do it with SSE:

```
__m128i sum1 = _mm_sad_epu8(u,v);
__m128i sum2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(sum1,2);
__m128i sum3 = _mm_add_epi16(sum1,sum2);
int8_t  sum4 = (int8_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum3);
```

I can't test this on AVX2 right now but here is untested code I would try first

```
__m256i sum1 = _mm256_sad_epu8(u,v);
__m256i sum2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(sum1,2);
__m256i sum3 = _mm256_add_epi16(sum1,sum2);  
__m128i sum4 = _mm_add_epi16(_mm256_castsi256_si128(sum3),
_mm256_extracti128_si256(sum3,1));
int8_t  sum5 = (int8_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum4);
```

I can test this later.

Answer (score 1):

Given the comments discussion above, I've drafted a working example of the use of the `VMPSADBW` instruction for 8x8 motion estimation. I'm somewhat disappointed by what GCC-4.8.1 generates for this, but this is a very good start. It includes two tests to verify the functionality as well as demonstrate use of my new function `sad_block_8x8_range()`.

The inner loop calculates the SAD of an 8x8 block against 8 overlapping blocks in the original image using 8 loads, 8 `VMPSADBW`s, 7 vertical adds, a shuffle and a reduction add. After masking out invalid SADs with `| 0xFFFFU`, the lowest SAD and its index is then immediately provided courtesy of `PHMINPOSUW`, an instruction that provides the minimum and index of the lowest of eight unsigned 16-bit values in an `xmm` register, and if this SAD is even lower than the current-best, it is saved together with said index.

```
/* Includes */
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>




/* Typedefs */
typedef uint8_t  u8;
typedef uint16_t u16;
typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef uint64_t u64;






/* Functions */

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @param [in]  orig   A pointer into the image within which to run ME. Points
 *                     to a base offset from which a window of maxDx pixels to
 *                     the right and maxDy pixels down is explored to find the
 *                     lowest SAD.
 * @param [in]  os     The span of the original image.
 * @param [in]  ref    A pointer to the 8x8 reference block being SAD-ed for in
 *                     the original image.
 * @param [in]  rs     The span of the 8x8 reference block.
 * @param [in]  maxDx  The width of the search window for ME. Cannot be 0.
 * @param [in]  maxDy  The height of the search window for ME. Cannot be 0.
 * @param [out] sadOut The lowest SAD found.
 * @param [out] dxOut  The corresponding best vector found, x-coordinate.
 * @param [out] dyOut  The corresponding best vector found, y-coordinate.
 */

void sad_block_8x8_range(const u8* orig,
                         unsigned  os,
                         const u8* ref,
                         unsigned  rs,
                         unsigned  maxDx,
                         unsigned  maxDy,
                         unsigned* sadOut,
                         unsigned* dxOut,
                         unsigned* dyOut){
    __m128  tmp01f, tmp23f, tmp45f, tmp67f;
    __m128i tmp01,  tmp23,  tmp45,  tmp67;
    __m256i r01,    r23,    r45,    r67;
    __m256i o0, o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7;
    const u8* refTmp;
    const u8* origTmp;
    int i;

    unsigned tmpDx, dx, dy, sad;
    unsigned minDx = 0, minDy = 0, minSAD = 0xFFFF;
    const static u16 MASKTBLw[] = {
        0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF,
        0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xFFFF,
    };
    const static __m128i* MASKTBL = (const __m128i*)MASKTBLw;

    /* Load the eight rows of 8 bytes of the reference block. */
    refTmp = ref;
    tmp01f = _mm_loadl_pi(tmp01f, (const __m64*)(refTmp));refTmp+=rs;/* tmp_a = [ x x x x x x x x 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 ] */
    tmp01f = _mm_loadh_pi(tmp01f, (const __m64*)(refTmp));refTmp+=rs;/* tmp_a = [ f e d c b a 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 ] */
    tmp23f = _mm_loadl_pi(tmp23f, (const __m64*)(refTmp));refTmp+=rs;
    tmp23f = _mm_loadh_pi(tmp23f, (const __m64*)(refTmp));refTmp+=rs;
    tmp45f = _mm_loadl_pi(tmp45f, (const __m64*)(refTmp));refTmp+=rs;
    tmp45f = _mm_loadh_pi(tmp45f, (const __m64*)(refTmp));refTmp+=rs;
    tmp67f = _mm_loadl_pi(tmp67f, (const __m64*)(refTmp));refTmp+=rs;
    tmp67f = _mm_loadh_pi(tmp67f, (const __m64*)(refTmp));
    tmp01  = _mm_castps_si128(tmp01f);/* A cast is needed to integer. */
    tmp23  = _mm_castps_si128(tmp23f);
    tmp45  = _mm_castps_si128(tmp45f);
    tmp67  = _mm_castps_si128(tmp67f);

    /**
     * Combine them into 4 ymm registers each holding two rows in duplicate;
     * One in high half and once in low half.
     */

    r01  = _mm256_inserti128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(tmp01), tmp01, 1);/* r_ab = [ f e d c b a 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 f e d c b a 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 ] */
    r23  = _mm256_inserti128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(tmp23), tmp23, 1);
    r45  = _mm256_inserti128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(tmp45), tmp45, 1);
    r67  = _mm256_inserti128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(tmp67), tmp67, 1);

    /* Iterate over x and y of search space. */
    for(dy=0;dy<maxDy;dy++){
        for(dx=0;dx<maxDx;dx+=8){
            /* Broadcast 16-byte rows to both halves of ymm register */
            origTmp = orig + dy*os + dx;
            o0 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp)));origTmp += os;
            o1 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp)));origTmp += os;
            o2 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp)));origTmp += os;
            o3 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp)));origTmp += os;
            o4 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp)));origTmp += os;
            o5 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp)));origTmp += os;
            o6 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp)));origTmp += os;

/**
 * Define to 0 if the image can be guaranteed to always have 8 extra allocated
 * bytes beyond its nominal end.
 */
#define NO_OVERALLOCATION 1
            if(NO_OVERALLOCATION && maxDx-dx < 9){/* i.e., maxDx+7-dx < 16, the load size. */
                /**
                 * Special-case code for last row.
                 *      maxDx+7-dx   is the number of bytes to be loaded.
                 *      maxDx-dx     is the number of valid elements.
                 */
#if 1
                __m128i dealigned = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp+maxDx-dx-9));
                __m128i shufmsk   = _mm_add_epi8(_mm_set_epi8(15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0),
                                                 _mm_set1_epi8(7));
                shufmsk = _mm_add_epi8(shufmsk, _mm_set1_epi8(maxDx-dx));
                o7 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_shuffle_epi8(dealigned, shufmsk));
#else
                u8 tmpArr[16] = {0};
                for(i=0;i < maxDx+7-dx;i++){
                    tmpArr[i] = (orig+(dy+7)*os+dx)[i];
                }
                o7 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(tmpArr)));
#endif
            }else{
                o7 = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(origTmp)));
            }


            /**
             * ACTUAL ACTION.
             * 
             * The upper 128-bit lane calculates the SAD for the right 4 bytes
             * of each row of the reference block, while the lower 128-bit lane
             * does similarly for the left 4 bytes of each row of the reference
             * block.
             * 
             * Once the individual SADs for each 4-byte half of each row are
             * obtained against eight consecutive neighbours, add the sixteen
             * 4-byte row halves to get the SADs for the full 8x8 blocks.
             * 
             * After masking for invalid entries, find the minimum SAD and its
             * index using PHMINPOSUW.
             * 
             * Compare the old to the new SAD and if it is a record-setter, save
             * it.
             */

            /* MPSADBWs */
            __m256i s0 = _mm256_mpsadbw_epu8(o0, r01, 1<<5 | 1<<3 | 0<<2 | 0<<0);
            __m256i s1 = _mm256_mpsadbw_epu8(o1, r01, 1<<5 | 3<<3 | 0<<2 | 2<<0);
            __m256i s2 = _mm256_mpsadbw_epu8(o2, r23, 1<<5 | 1<<3 | 0<<2 | 0<<0);
            __m256i s3 = _mm256_mpsadbw_epu8(o3, r23, 1<<5 | 3<<3 | 0<<2 | 2<<0);
            __m256i s4 = _mm256_mpsadbw_epu8(o4, r45, 1<<5 | 1<<3 | 0<<2 | 0<<0);
            __m256i s5 = _mm256_mpsadbw_epu8(o5, r45, 1<<5 | 3<<3 | 0<<2 | 2<<0);
            __m256i s6 = _mm256_mpsadbw_epu8(o6, r67, 1<<5 | 1<<3 | 0<<2 | 0<<0);
            __m256i s7 = _mm256_mpsadbw_epu8(o7, r67, 1<<5 | 3<<3 | 0<<2 | 2<<0);

            /* Accumulate half-row results together into half-block results */
            s0 = _mm256_add_epi16(s0, s1);
            s0 = _mm256_add_epi16(s0, s2);
            s0 = _mm256_add_epi16(s0, s3);
            s0 = _mm256_add_epi16(s0, s4);
            s0 = _mm256_add_epi16(s0, s5);
            s0 = _mm256_add_epi16(s0, s6);
            s0 = _mm256_add_epi16(s0, s7);

            /* Accumulate half-block results into block results */
            __m128i t0 = _mm256_extracti128_si256(s0, 0);
            __m128i t1 = _mm256_extracti128_si256(s0, 1);
            __m128i t  = _mm_add_epi16(t0, t1);

            /* Find horizontal minimum using PHMINPOSUW */
            __m128i hm = maxDx-dx < 8 ? MASKTBL[maxDx-dx] : _mm_setzero_si128();
            __m128i h  = _mm_minpos_epu16(_mm_or_si128(t, hm));
            sad   =      (u16)_mm_extract_epi16(h, 0);
            tmpDx = dx + (u16)_mm_extract_epi16(h, 1);

            /* Save the result if it is the best so far. */
            if(sad < minSAD){
                minDx  = tmpDx;
                minDy  = dy;
                minSAD = sad;
            }
        }
    }

    sadOut && (*sadOut = minSAD);
    dxOut  && (*dxOut  = minDx);
    dyOut  && (*dyOut  = minDy);
}

/**
 * MAIN.
 * 
 * Runs two testcases.
 */

int main(){
    const u8 ref[] = {
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
        0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
        0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
        0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
        0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27,
        0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f,
        0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37,
        0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f,
    };
    const u8 img0[] = {
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF
    };
    const u8 img1[] = {
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x40,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF
    };
    unsigned sad, dx, dy;


    sad_block_8x8_range(img0, 16, ref, 8, 9, 9, &sad, &dx, &dy);
    if(sad == 0 && dx == 7 && dy == 3){
        printf("Test 1 PASSED!\n");
    }else{
        printf("Test 1 FAILED! (SAD = %u, MV=(%u, %u))\n", sad, dx, dy);
    }


    sad_block_8x8_range(img1, 16, ref, 8, 9, 9, &sad, &dx, &dy);
    if(sad == 1 && dx == 8 && dy == 4){
        printf("Test 2 PASSED!\n");
    }else{
        printf("Test 2 FAILED! (SAD = %u, MV=(%u, %u))\n", sad, dx, dy);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I have assumed that you want to optimize the following code:

```
int sad_2x64_normal(uint8_t *ptr0, uint8_t *ptr1)
{
  int  sum = 0;
  int  v0,v1;  
  for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    v0 = static_cast<int>(*ptr0++);
    v1 = static_cast<int>(*ptr1++);
    sum += abs(v0-v1);
  }
  return sum;
}
```

The question is tagged with AVX2, my short solution is

```
int sad_2x64_avx2(uint8_t *ptr0, uint8_t *ptr1)
{
  register __m256i  r0;
  register __m256i  r1;
  register __m256i  r2;
  register __m256i  r3;

  r0 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const *>(ptr0)); // load 32 bytes (aligned)
  r1 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const *>(ptr1)); // load 32 bytes (aligned)

  r2 = _mm256_sad_epu8(r0, r1);    // 4 unsigned 64 bit value

  r0 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const *>(ptr0+32));
  r1 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const *>(ptr1+32));

  r3 = _mm256_sad_epu8(r0, r1);   

  r2 = _mm256_add_epi16(r2, r3);
  r2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(r2, 0xE8);    
  r2 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(r2, r2);
  r2 = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(r2, 0xE8);
  r2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(r2, 0xE8);   
  r2 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(r2, r2);    
  return _mm_extract_epi16(_mm256_castsi256_si128(r2), 0);
}
```

Same but with all the comments

```
#include "emmintrin.h"
#include "immintrin.h"

// 
// returns \sum_0^{63} abs(ptr0[i]-ptr1[i])
// assume ptr0 and ptr1 are 32 byte aligned
//
int sad_2x64_avx2(uint8_t *ptr0, uint8_t *ptr1)
{
  register __m256i  r0;
  register __m256i  r1;
  register __m256i  r2;
  register __m256i  r3;

  // 1st 32 bytes

  r0 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const *>(ptr0));    // load 32 bytes (aligned)
  r1 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const *>(ptr1));    // load 32 bytes (aligned)

  r2 = _mm256_sad_epu8(r0, r1);    // results stored as 4x64

  // 2nd 32 bytes

  r0 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const *>(ptr0+32));    // load 32 bytes (aligned)
  r1 = _mm256_load_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i const *>(ptr1+32));    // load 32 bytes (aligned)

  r3 = _mm256_sad_epu8(r0, r1);


  // after sad_epu8
  //
  //       255                             127             63      31
  //      |                               |               |       |
  // r2 = | 0 | 0 | 0 | a | 0 | 0 | 0 | b | 0 | 0 | 0 | c | 0 | 0 | 0 | d |
  // r3 = | 0 | 0 | 0 | e | 0 | 0 | 0 | f | 0 | 0 | 0 | g | 0 | 0 | 0 | h | 

  r2 = _mm256_add_epi16(r2, r3); 

  // after add_epi16
  //
  //       255                             127             63      31
  //      |                               |               |       |
  // r2 = | 0 | 0 | 0 | i | 0 | 0 | 0 | j | 0 | 0 | 0 | k | 0 | 0 | 0 | l |

  r2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(r2, 0xE8); // binary 11_10_10_00

  // after shuffle
  //
  //       255                             127             63      31
  //      |                               |               |       |
  // r2 = | 0 | 0 | 0 | i | 0 | i | 0 | j | 0 | 0 | 0 | k | 0 | k | 0 | l | 

  r2 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(r2, r2);  

  // after hadd
  //
  //       255                             127             63      31
  //      |                               |               |       |
  // r2 = |     i |   i+j |     i |  i+j  |     k |   k+l |     k |   k+l | 

  r2 = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(r2, 0xE8); // 11_10_10_00
  r2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi32(r2, 0xE8); // binary 11_10_10_00

  // after permute and shuffle
  //
  //       255                             127             63      31
  //      |                               |               |       |
  // r2 = |     i |   i+j |   i+j |  i+j  |     i |   i+j |   i+j |   k+l | 

  r2 = _mm256_hadd_epi32(r2, r2);

  // after hadd and shuffle
  //
  //       255                             127             63      31
  //      |                               |               |       |
  // r2 = | ....  | ....  | ....  | ....  |  .... | ....  | ....  |i+j+k+l| 


  return _mm_extract_epi16(_mm256_castsi256_si128(r2), 0);
}
```

Hope it helps!

On my machine (Haswell Core i7 4900MQ) with g++ 4.8.2

```
g++ -march=core-avx2 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -O3 ...
```

I have observed a speed up of x58 between the normal and the avx2 version!